# How to release the reference in a Server DCOM when the client crashes the connection

Tags: delphi, com, client-server, distributed-computing

In a Client / Server environment, where the server implements the COM interface, there are cases where the connection is lost for some reason (client crashes), but the instance of the thread it stays active on the server, consuming memory until the application is finalized .
There are some way to destroy the instances inactive by the server?

Server using `TRemoteDataModule` and client `TDComConnection`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DCOM garbage collection](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0398/dcom.aspx) does this automatically. After the three missed pings at 120 second intervals, the connection will be cleaned up.

So you have nothing to do. You can sit back and let the system do the work.

Comment: Are you sure that this works? I tested with the server and client on the same machine and it did not work after 8 minutes, now I'm testing with client and server on separate machines.
In all test cases, the thread model is MTA, connecting once with just one client and finalizing the client through taskkill.

Comment: COM GC is an ancient technology and known to work. Perhaps something in your server is stopping it.

Comment: like what? connection remaining active with database?

Comment: I don't know. Make a trivial do nothing COM server/client. And check that it works there. Then work out where you setup differs.